# Getting Access Denied

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am trying to open ie11 using selnium web driver and java.

My code looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
    "C:\\Users\\ankit.pande\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
    options.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    WebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    String url = "https://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/";
    webDriver.navigate().to(url);
    webDriver.close();
}
```

I have changed the registry settings and Enabled protected mode(for all options)..Still I am getting

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unexpected error
>   launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070005
>   ('Access is denied.') for URL 'http://localhost:15641/'

error

Comment: The links were not of any help. I have done the registry setting and enabled protected  mode for all options. I tried the desired capabilities, but it is showing the same error as stated above.

Comment: Are you logged in OS as 'ankit.pande'?

Comment: Yes I am logged in as ankit.pande. I am even using a compatible web driver. Please help me out I ca  provide screen shots too.

Comment: Check access rights on folder Downloads, maybe set full control for everyone. It's Windows issue I guess.